# AWS Mobile Hub - How to Implement User Sign In Without Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, aws-sdk, aws-mobilehub

I am currently working on a project that does not include storyboards and I am trying to create a user authentication and sign-in method. I was initially going to use FireBase but they did not have Carthage support so I decided to try out AWS. I initially tried using AWSCognitoIdentityProvider framework with my custom UI but the passwordauthentication method for signing in would not trigger a result. I moved onto the AWSAuthUI framework (plus AWSAuthCore, AWSFacebookSignIn, AWSGoogleSignIn, AWSUserPoolsSignIn) with the built in UI but I keep getting the error below before even getting to the login screen.

" Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'SignIn' in bundle NSBundle "

From all the documentation and demo applications that I've seen, I guess this is not possible without using storyboards? Can someone please confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the Storyboard files in the Build Phases if you are using Carthage: See an example here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/pull/733/files. Currently the AuthUI implements the UI components in a storyboard file.

Comment: The UI shows up but the google and facebook buttons are not responding. In my sample project from Amazon, they work but I cannot seem to figure out why they are not working. I have everything in the plist file that the sample project has and aws-config is updated.

Comment: Thank you @RushB for the reply. Have you added the awsconfiguration.json file to the xcode project and does the file belong to the target? Also when you click the facebook signin button, do you get any exception in the xcode console?

Comment: Hi @Karthikeyan, No there is no exception or any error displayed. The target is correct. In my AppDelegate I am doing this :AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance().setPermissions(["public_profile", "email"])
        AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().register(signInProvider: AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance()) for each type.

Comment: Thank you @RushB for the quick reply. Can you check the sample app from the AWS Mobile Hub Console which demonstrates using the Facebook SignIn button? As a check, did you add interceptApplication callback in application:url:sourceApplication:annotation callback in AppDelegate?  What version of SDK are you using?

Comment: If that doesn't work any further, can you personal message me so that we can look at the code and I will be able to help better over e-mail?

Comment: Hi @Karthikeyan, I am using the latest version of aws (2.6.13) and I do have add interceptApplication working. I can use all the features (login, forget password etc) except for the GoogleSignIn and FacebookSignIn. I haven't unlocked messaging on stack overflow, perhaps somewhere else? I really appreciate the help!